# Total number of posts in query (category/tag/author/search results/main page...)

Tags: posts, pages, pagination, search

I want to know the total number of posts from the category/tag/author/search result that I am actually seeing.

Say for example I am in the main page. If my posts_per_page are 10 and my pagination shows 6 pages, that would mean there are a number of posts in my query between 51 and 60.

How could I get that exact number?

I would like it to work for every category,search results... from my web.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!-- displays total number of posts for query, ignoring pagination -->
<?php echo $wp_query->found_posts ?>
```